# How to replace a single character in a string?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I'm trying to replace a character in a string after getting the string as input from the user super simple like this:

```bsh
$thestring = Read-Host;
```

And now I want to change the 2nd character of the string. I don't care what letter the 2nd char is, but it needs to be set to 'a'.

I found the `Replace()` method to replace a chosen character:

```bsh
$thestring = $string.Replace('b','a');
```

But it only goes for a given character. In C++ I would just say something like

```cpp
thestring[1] = 'a';
```

And I'm trying to find something equal in PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same in PowerShell if you cast the string to a character array:

```
[char[]]$char = $thestring
$char[1] = 'a'
```

Use the [`-join` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847757.aspx) to convert the character array back to a string:

```
-join $char
$char -join ''
```

Other options are the [`Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
$thestring.Substring(0,1) + 'a' + $thestring.Substring(2, $thestring.Length-2)
```

or [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [replacements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx):

```
$thestring -replace '^(.).(.*)', '${1}a${2}'
```

Comment: FYI, `[string]::new($char)` is 100+ times faster than `-join`